# 20+ functions for generating different waveforms

Tags: python, signal-processing, scipy

[I added](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6407) a [guard clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) to the functions in `scipy.signal.windows`, but the way they are currently written means the same 11 lines are now repeated in every function.

Each function has a unique core and a unique docstring, then some common guards and preconditioning around it:

```
if int(M) != M or M < 0:
    raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
if M == 0:
    return np.array([])
if M == 1:
    return np.ones(1, 'd')
odd = M % 2
if not sym and not odd:
    M = M + 1

...

if not sym and not odd:
    w = w[:-1]
return w
```

So I thought I'd factor out the common code to make it more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  However I can't find a really elegant way to do it:

- Moving the redundant code into helper functions doesn't work because the [early exits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit) don't work nested inside another function.  Adding more code to catch the early exits kind of defeats the purpose.
- [Wrapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) them in a decorator changes the function signature from `blackman(M, sym=True)` to `blackman(M, *args)`, since some window functions have different numbers of arguments than others.
- [Splitting the unique guts of each function out into their own `_core` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38517441/125507) would work, but seems a little mangled, with the actual code being separated  from the docstrings.

[The complete file is here](https://github.com/endolith/scipy/blob/f256dda706dd7b308993620b48b66f052dc4ecd0/scipy/signal/windows.py).  Removed parts to make it less lengthy, while still showing some docstrings and functions with different numbers of arguments:

```
"""The suite of window functions."""
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import warnings

import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack, linalg, special
from scipy._lib.six import string_types

__all__ = ['boxcar', 'triang', 'parzen', 'bohman', 'blackman', 'nuttall',
           'blackmanharris', 'flattop', 'bartlett', 'hanning', 'barthann',
           'hamming', 'kaiser', 'gaussian', 'general_gaussian', 'chebwin',
           'slepian', 'cosine', 'hann', 'exponential', 'tukey', 'get_window']
...    

def triang(M, sym=True):
    """Return a triangular window.

    Parameters
    ----------
    M : int
        Number of points in the output window. If zero or less, an empty
        array is returned.
    sym : bool, optional
        When True (default), generates a symmetric window, for use in filter
        design.
        When False, generates a periodic window, for use in spectral analysis.

    Returns
    -------
    w : ndarray
        The window, with the maximum value normalized to 1 (though the value 1
        does not appear if `M` is even and `sym` is True).

    Examples
    --------
    Plot the window and its frequency response:

    >>> from scipy import signal
    >>> from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftshift
    >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    >>> window = signal.triang(51)
    >>> plt.plot(window)
    >>> plt.title("Triangular window")
    >>> plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Sample")

    >>> plt.figure()
    >>> A = fft(window, 2048) / (len(window)/2.0)
    >>> freq = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, len(A))
    >>> response = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(fftshift(A / abs(A).max())))
    >>> plt.plot(freq, response)
    >>> plt.axis([-0.5, 0.5, -120, 0])
    >>> plt.title("Frequency response of the triangular window")
    >>> plt.ylabel("Normalized magnitude [dB]")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Normalized frequency [cycles per sample]")

    """
    if int(M) != M or M < 0:
        raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
    if M == 0:
        return np.array([])
    if M == 1:
        return np.ones(1, 'd')
    odd = M % 2
    if not sym and not odd:
        M = M + 1
    n = np.arange(1, (M + 1) // 2 + 1)
    if M % 2 == 0:
        w = (2 * n - 1.0) / M
        w = np.r_[w, w[::-1]]
    else:
        w = 2 * n / (M + 1.0)
        w = np.r_[w, w[-2::-1]]

    if not sym and not odd:
        w = w[:-1]
    return w


def parzen(M, sym=True):
    """Return a Parzen window.
...    
    """
    if int(M) != M or M < 0:
        raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
    if M == 0:
        return np.array([])
    if M == 1:
        return np.ones(1, 'd')
    odd = M % 2
    if not sym and not odd:
        M = M + 1
    n = np.arange(-(M - 1) / 2.0, (M - 1) / 2.0 + 0.5, 1.0)
    na = np.extract(n < -(M - 1) / 4.0, n)
    nb = np.extract(abs(n) <= (M - 1) / 4.0, n)
    wa = 2 * (1 - np.abs(na) / (M / 2.0)) ** 3.0
    wb = (1 - 6 * (np.abs(nb) / (M / 2.0)) ** 2.0 +
          6 * (np.abs(nb) / (M / 2.0)) ** 3.0)
    w = np.r_[wa, wb, wa[::-1]]
    if not sym and not odd:
        w = w[:-1]
    return w

...


def tukey(M, alpha=0.5, sym=True):
    r"""Return a Tukey window, also known as a tapered cosine window.
... 
    """
    if int(M) != M or M < 0:
        raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
    if M == 0:
        return np.array([])
    if M == 1:
        return np.ones(1, 'd')

    if alpha <= 0:
        return np.ones(M, 'd')
    elif alpha >= 1.0:
        return hann(M, sym=sym)

    odd = M % 2
    if not sym and not odd:
        M = M + 1

    n = np.arange(0, M)
    width = int(np.floor(alpha*(M-1)/2.0))
    n1 = n[0:width+1]
    n2 = n[width+1:M-width-1]
    n3 = n[M-width-1:]

    w1 = 0.5 * (1 + np.cos(np.pi * (-1 + 2.0*n1/alpha/(M-1))))
    w2 = np.ones(n2.shape)
    w3 = 0.5 * (1 + np.cos(np.pi * (-2.0/alpha + 1 + 2.0*n3/alpha/(M-1))))

    w = np.concatenate((w1, w2, w3))

    if not sym and not odd:
        w = w[:-1]
    return w

...    

def slepian(M, width, sym=True):
    """Return a digital Slepian (DPSS) window.
...
    """
    if int(M) != M or M < 0:
        raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
    if M == 0:
        return np.array([])
    if M == 1:
        return np.ones(1, 'd')
    odd = M % 2
    if not sym and not odd:
        M = M + 1

    # our width is the full bandwidth
    width = width / 2
    # to match the old version
    width = width / 2
    m = np.arange(M, dtype='d')
    H = np.zeros((2, M))
    H[0, 1:] = m[1:] * (M - m[1:]) / 2
    H[1, :] = ((M - 1 - 2 * m) / 2)**2 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * width)

    _, win = linalg.eig_banded(H, select='i', select_range=(M-1, M-1))
    win = win.ravel() / win.max()

    if not sym and not odd:
        win = win[:-1]
    return win
...    

def exponential(M, center=None, tau=1., sym=True):
    r"""Return an exponential (or Poisson) window.

    Parameters
    ----------
    M : int
        Number of points in the output window. If zero or less, an empty
        array is returned.
    center : float, optional
        Parameter defining the center location of the window function.
        The default value if not given is ``center = (M-1) / 2``.  This
        parameter must take its default value for symmetric windows.
    tau : float, optional
        Parameter defining the decay.  For ``center = 0`` use
        ``tau = -(M-1) / ln(x)`` if ``x`` is the fraction of the window
        remaining at the end.
    sym : bool, optional
        When True (default), generates a symmetric window, for use in filter
        design.
        When False, generates a periodic window, for use in spectral analysis.

    Returns
    -------
    w : ndarray
        The window, with the maximum value normalized to 1 (though the value 1
        does not appear if `M` is even and `sym` is True).

    Notes
    -----
    The Exponential window is defined as

    .. math::  w(n) = e^{-|n-center| / \tau}

    References
    ----------
    S. Gade and H. Herlufsen, "Windows to FFT analysis (Part I)",
    Technical Review 3, Bruel & Kjaer, 1987.

    Examples
    --------
    Plot the symmetric window and its frequency response:

    >>> from scipy import signal
    >>> from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftshift
    >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    >>> M = 51
    >>> tau = 3.0
    >>> window = signal.exponential(M, tau=tau)
    >>> plt.plot(window)
    >>> plt.title("Exponential Window (tau=3.0)")
    >>> plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Sample")

    >>> plt.figure()
    >>> A = fft(window, 2048) / (len(window)/2.0)
    >>> freq = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, len(A))
    >>> response = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(fftshift(A / abs(A).max())))
    >>> plt.plot(freq, response)
    >>> plt.axis([-0.5, 0.5, -35, 0])
    >>> plt.title("Frequency response of the Exponential window (tau=3.0)")
    >>> plt.ylabel("Normalized magnitude [dB]")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Normalized frequency [cycles per sample]")

    This function can also generate non-symmetric windows:

    >>> tau2 = -(M-1) / np.log(0.01)
    >>> window2 = signal.exponential(M, 0, tau2, False)
    >>> plt.figure()
    >>> plt.plot(window2)
    >>> plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Sample")
    """
    if sym and center is not None:
        raise ValueError("If sym==True, center must be None.")
    if int(M) != M or M < 0:
        raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
    if M == 0:
        return np.array([])
    if M == 1:
        return np.ones(1, 'd')
    odd = M % 2
    if not sym and not odd:
        M = M + 1
    if center is None:
        center = (M-1) / 2

    n = np.arange(0, M)
    w = np.exp(-np.abs(n-center) / tau)
    if not sym and not odd:
        w = w[:-1]

    return w

...
```

Answer (score 6):

I do believe that the decorator way is the proper one. There are some tradeoff using it but you can easily overcome your main concern using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps): it will reuse the name, docstring and signature of the decorated function for the wrapper.

The wrapper within the decorator should be aware of both `M` and `sym`; this is where things can get tricky depending on how you want things to behave.

A first approach could be:

```
from functools import wraps


def argument_checker(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(M, *args, sym=True, **kwargs):
        if int(M) != M or M < 0:
            raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
        if M == 0:
            return np.array([])
        if M == 1:
            return np.ones(1, 'd')

        if not sym and not M % 2:
            return func(M + 1, *args, **kwargs)[:-1]
        else:
            return func(M, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I just modified the boilerplate code to group the two `if not sym and not odd` into a single `if` as there is `func` that abstract the `window` building. However this solution is Python 3 only as the signature of `wrapper` will raise a `SyntaxError` in Python 2, and as regard to your imports from `__future__`, I'm assuming Python 2 here. So you might want:

```
def argument_checker(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(M, *args, **kwargs):
        sym = kwargs.pop('sym', True)
        ...
```

But this poses the issue of `sym` needing to be a keyword argument, and not a positional one. Again, this can be made more explicit using Python 3 syntax for keyword-only arguments:

```
def triang(M, *, sym=True):
    ...
```

or

```
def tukey(M, alpha=0.5, *, sym=True):
    ...
```

Which, when called naturally using `triang(150, False)`, for instance, will raise `TypeError: triang() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

So I'd go for this second version and keep the current signature of the functions for now, but if you can use Python 3 instead, it will be made much more explicit. I would, however, remove the `*args` parameter from the wrapper to make it accept only keyword arguments.

But then, there is the case of `tukey` that add an other layer of check into the checks. To handle that properly, it is easier to split the decorator into two, more meaningful, tasks:

```
from functools import wraps


def argument_checker(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(M, **kwargs):
        if int(M) != M or M < 0:
            raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
        if M == 0:
            return np.array([])
        if M == 1:
            return np.ones(1, 'd')

        return func(M, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def parity_handler(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(M, **kwargs):
        sym = kwargs.get('sym', True)
        if not sym and not M % 2:
            return func(M + 1, **kwargs)[:-1]
        else:
            return func(M, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

So you can

```
@argument_checker
@parity_handler
def triang(M, sym=True):
    ...
```

But most importantly:

```
def alpha_handler(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(M, **kwargs):
        alpha = kwargs.get('alpha', 0.5)
        if alpha <= 0:
            return np.ones(M, 'd')
        elif alpha >= 1.0:
            return hann(M, sym=kwargs.get('sym', True))
        return func(M, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@argument_checker
@alpha_handler
@parity_handler
def tukey(...
```

And the whole module could become:

```
"""The suite of window functions."""
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import warnings
from functools import wraps

import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack, linalg, special
from scipy._lib.six import string_types

__all__ = ['boxcar', 'triang', 'parzen', 'bohman', 'blackman', 'nuttall',
           'blackmanharris', 'flattop', 'bartlett', 'hanning', 'barthann',
           'hamming', 'kaiser', 'gaussian', 'general_gaussian', 'chebwin',
           'slepian', 'cosine', 'hann', 'exponential', 'tukey', 'get_window']
...    


def argument_checker(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(M, **kwargs):
        if int(M) != M or M < 0:
            raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
        if M == 0:
            return np.array([])
        if M == 1:
            return np.ones(1, 'd')

        return func(M, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def parity_handler(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(M, **kwargs):
        sym = kwargs.get('sym', True)
        if not sym and not M % 2:
            return func(M + 1, **kwargs)[:-1]
        else:
            return func(M, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@argument_checker
@parity_handler
def triang(M, sym=True):
    """Return a triangular window.

    Parameters
    ----------
    M : int
        Number of points in the output window. If zero or less, an empty
        array is returned.
    sym : bool, optional
        When True (default), generates a symmetric window, for use in filter
        design.
        When False, generates a periodic window, for use in spectral analysis.

    Returns
    -------
    w : ndarray
        The window, with the maximum value normalized to 1 (though the value 1
        does not appear if `M` is even and `sym` is True).

    Examples
    --------
    Plot the window and its frequency response:

    >>> from scipy import signal
    >>> from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftshift
    >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    >>> window = signal.triang(51)
    >>> plt.plot(window)
    >>> plt.title("Triangular window")
    >>> plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Sample")

    >>> plt.figure()
    >>> A = fft(window, 2048) / (len(window)/2.0)
    >>> freq = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, len(A))
    >>> response = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(fftshift(A / abs(A).max())))
    >>> plt.plot(freq, response)
    >>> plt.axis([-0.5, 0.5, -120, 0])
    >>> plt.title("Frequency response of the triangular window")
    >>> plt.ylabel("Normalized magnitude [dB]")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Normalized frequency [cycles per sample]")

    """
    n = np.arange(1, (M + 1) // 2 + 1)
    if M % 2 == 0:
        w = (2 * n - 1.0) / M
        w = np.r_[w, w[::-1]]
    else:
        w = 2 * n / (M + 1.0)
        w = np.r_[w, w[-2::-1]]
    return w


@argument_checker
@parity_handler
def parzen(M, sym=True):
    """Return a Parzen window.
...    
    """
    n = np.arange(-(M - 1) / 2.0, (M - 1) / 2.0 + 0.5, 1.0)
    na = np.extract(n < -(M - 1) / 4.0, n)
    nb = np.extract(abs(n) <= (M - 1) / 4.0, n)
    wa = 2 * (1 - np.abs(na) / (M / 2.0)) ** 3.0
    wb = (1 - 6 * (np.abs(nb) / (M / 2.0)) ** 2.0 +
          6 * (np.abs(nb) / (M / 2.0)) ** 3.0)
    w = np.r_[wa, wb, wa[::-1]]
    return w

...


def alpha_handler(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(M, **kwargs):
        alpha = kwargs.get('alpha', 0.5)
        if alpha <= 0:
            return np.ones(M, 'd')
        elif alpha >= 1.0:
            return hann(M, sym=kwargs.get('sym', True))
        return func(M, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@argument_checker
@alpha_handler
@parity_handler
def tukey(M, alpha=0.5, sym=True):
    r"""Return a Tukey window, also known as a tapered cosine window.
... 
    """    
    n = np.arange(0, M)
    width = int(np.floor(alpha*(M-1)/2.0))
    n1 = n[0:width+1]
    n2 = n[width+1:M-width-1]
    n3 = n[M-width-1:]

    w1 = 0.5 * (1 + np.cos(np.pi * (-1 + 2.0*n1/alpha/(M-1))))
    w2 = np.ones(n2.shape)
    w3 = 0.5 * (1 + np.cos(np.pi * (-2.0/alpha + 1 + 2.0*n3/alpha/(M-1))))

    w = np.concatenate((w1, w2, w3))

    return w

...    

@argument_checker
@parity_handler
def slepian(M, width, sym=True):
    """Return a digital Slepian (DPSS) window.
...
    """    
    # our width is the full bandwidth
    width = width / 2
    # to match the old version
    width = width / 2
    m = np.arange(M, dtype='d')
    H = np.zeros((2, M))
    H[0, 1:] = m[1:] * (M - m[1:]) / 2
    H[1, :] = ((M - 1 - 2 * m) / 2)**2 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * width)

    _, win = linalg.eig_banded(H, select='i', select_range=(M-1, M-1))
    win = win.ravel() / win.max()

    return win
...    

@argument_checker
@parity_handler
def exponential(M, center=None, tau=1., sym=True):
    r"""Return an exponential (or Poisson) window.

    Parameters
    ----------
    M : int
        Number of points in the output window. If zero or less, an empty
        array is returned.
    center : float, optional
        Parameter defining the center location of the window function.
        The default value if not given is ``center = (M-1) / 2``.  This
        parameter must take its default value for symmetric windows.
    tau : float, optional
        Parameter defining the decay.  For ``center = 0`` use
        ``tau = -(M-1) / ln(x)`` if ``x`` is the fraction of the window
        remaining at the end.
    sym : bool, optional
        When True (default), generates a symmetric window, for use in filter
        design.
        When False, generates a periodic window, for use in spectral analysis.

    Returns
    -------
    w : ndarray
        The window, with the maximum value normalized to 1 (though the value 1
        does not appear if `M` is even and `sym` is True).

    Notes
    -----
    The Exponential window is defined as

    .. math::  w(n) = e^{-|n-center| / \tau}

    References
    ----------
    S. Gade and H. Herlufsen, "Windows to FFT analysis (Part I)",
    Technical Review 3, Bruel & Kjaer, 1987.

    Examples
    --------
    Plot the symmetric window and its frequency response:

    >>> from scipy import signal
    >>> from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftshift
    >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    >>> M = 51
    >>> tau = 3.0
    >>> window = signal.exponential(M, tau=tau)
    >>> plt.plot(window)
    >>> plt.title("Exponential Window (tau=3.0)")
    >>> plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Sample")

    >>> plt.figure()
    >>> A = fft(window, 2048) / (len(window)/2.0)
    >>> freq = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, len(A))
    >>> response = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(fftshift(A / abs(A).max())))
    >>> plt.plot(freq, response)
    >>> plt.axis([-0.5, 0.5, -35, 0])
    >>> plt.title("Frequency response of the Exponential window (tau=3.0)")
    >>> plt.ylabel("Normalized magnitude [dB]")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Normalized frequency [cycles per sample]")

    This function can also generate non-symmetric windows:

    >>> tau2 = -(M-1) / np.log(0.01)
    >>> window2 = signal.exponential(M, 0, tau2, False)
    >>> plt.figure()
    >>> plt.plot(window2)
    >>> plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
    >>> plt.xlabel("Sample")
    """
    if sym and center is not None:
        raise ValueError("If sym==True, center must be None.")
    if center is None:
        center = (M-1) / 2

    n = np.arange(0, M)
    w = np.exp(-np.abs(n-center) / tau)

    return w

...
```

You can also blend the same approach than for `tukey` into `exponential` if you want to check for `if sym and center is not None:` earlier.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The `@wraps(func)` lines shouldn't have colons after them?  My main concern was that this changes the function signature, though.  It's now `Signature: tukey(M, **kwargs)` instead of `Signature: tukey(M, alpha=0.5, sym=True)`

Comment: `wraps` will make `help` display the old signature. But yes, the actual one is now `tukey(M, **kwargs)` which will make both `tukey(10, 0.3, True)` fail (no keywords) and `tukey(1, foo='bar')` succed (and return `np.ones(1, 'd')`). But `tukey(10, foo='bar')` will fail because, in the end, it will call the "real" `tukey` which doesn't accept foo as parameter. It's part of the tradeoff I mentionned. And the Python 3 syntax `tukey(M, *, alpha=0.5, sym=True)` can make it much more explicit.

Comment: If I understand correctly, [the decorator module](http://pythonhosted.org/decorator/documentation.html) fixes the signature issue?

Comment: @endolith Sounds like it does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to thinking functional-programming-style, but I'm going to give it a shot.

The way I see it, each of these functions looks like

```
postprocess( core( preprocess( M ) ) )
```

We don't actually want to make new `_core` functions, however, so perhaps a *little bit* of sufficiently generic and adaptable boilerplate is acceptable. Unfortunately, this *will* come at the cost of code complexity, but hopefully, comments will illustrate intent, and make code maintenance easier in future.

To start off with, we could have

```
def _preprocess(M, sym):
    if int(M) != M or M < 0:
        raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
    if M == 0:
        raise ReturnException(np.array([]))
    if M == 1:
        return ReturnException(np.ones(1, 'd'))
    odd = M % 2
    if not sym and not odd:
        M = M + 1
    return M
```

so that the starting boiler plate is reduced to something like:

```
def triang(M, sym=True):
    try:
        M = _preprocess(M, sym)
    except ReturnException as r:
        return r.value
```

`ReturnException` is something I'm defining a la "`MyError`" defined in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions).

But of course, all of this will not work for core-function-specific boilerplate. But coming to that later...

Then, we have a post-processing function:

```
def _postprocess(w, sym):
    if not sym and not odd:
        w = w[:-1]
    return w
```

and in each of the core functions, simply:

```
return _postprocess(w, sym)
```

If you really want to explicitly have function-specific steps happening at some *stage* during the pre-processing process, then you might want to consider adding a hook for that too (for example, in the `tukey` function in your question)

```
def _preprocess(M, sym, core_specific_fn, *args, **kwargs):
        if int(M) != M or M < 0:
    raise ValueError('Window length M must be a non-negative integer')
if M == 0:
    return np.array([])
if M == 1:
    return np.ones(1, 'd')

M, sym = core_specific_fn(M, sym, *args, **kwargs)

odd = M % 2
if not sym and not odd:
    M = M + 1
```

with the `core_specific_fn` being defined in `tukey` itself, and raising a return exception too. Preprocess will be called after this "sub-function" has been defined.

But in the `tukey` case, this is really not necessary. Just in case it *is* necessary somewhere else though...

But I should add that all this might not be worth the extra complexity it adds to the code. Especially if things like the additional hook from `tukey` is a common occurrence across the twenty functions.